# How to add and delete data to a json file from a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

How to insert and delete one key value pair from php file to JSON file as shown in demo below?

insert.php

```
$pname="Superman";
$pid="3";
```

delete.php

```
 $pname="Pikachu";
 $pid="1";
```

obdatabase.json

```
var pdatabase= '{ "pobject" : [' +
'{ "pname":"Pikachu" , "pid":"1" },' +
'{ "pname":"Squirtle" , "pid":"2" },' +
'{ "pname":"Justinbieber" , "pid":"3" }]}';
```

Comment: Why are you constructing the json string manually? Why not use json_encode()?

Comment: You should store json in your json file, not javascript.  Using javascript will make it a lot harder to parse in php.

Answer (score 2):

I would build a php array with whatever key-value data I need and then modify that array as needed (add / remove) before using `json_encode($myArray)` on that array to output a json formatted string.

**Note:** if you already have a json string available you can use that string to create a php array using something like `$myArray = json_decode($myJsonString)`.

---

Once you have a php array `$myArray` you can add key-value pairs like so:

```
$myArray['key'] = $value;
```

And you can remove key-value pairs like so:

```
unset($myArray['key']);
```

Comment: How to format the $myArray in using the example in my demo?

Comment: @ryanpika I have updated my answer to demonstrate how to modify the php array key-value pairs

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` and `json_decode` to work with JSON objects:

```
$array = array
(
    'pobject' => array
    ( 
        array('pname'=>'Pikachu', 'pid'=>1),
        ( ... )
    )
 );
```

then, to add an element - i.e. - to `pobject`:

```
$array['pobject'][] = array('pname'=>'Superman', 'pid'=>3);
( ... )
```

at the end of your job, you can encode it in JSON:

```
$json = json_encode( $array );
```

and re-decoding in *object/array* mode:

```
$array = json_decode( $json );
```

or in *only-array* mode:

```
$array = json_decode( $json, True );
```

---

- See more about [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- See more about [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)