# Append data to Json from PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to append `{ "pname":"superman" , "pid":"4" }`to the obdatabase.json. But my attempt below completely overwrite the json file.
How do I modify this?

obdatabase.json

```
{ "pobject":[{ "pname":"Pikachu" , "pid":"1" },
{ "pname":"squirtle" , "pid":"2" },
{ "pname":"Justinbieber" , "pid":"3" }]}
```

add.php

```
<?php

$file="obdatabase.json";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),TRUE);

$json['pobject'] = array('pname'=>'Superman', 'pid'=>4);

file_put_contents('obdatabase.json', json_encode($json));

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you write:

```
$json['pobject'] = array('pname'=>'Superman', 'pid'=>4);
```

By this way, you **replace** the `$json['pobject']` array instead of adding a value.

You have to use this syntax:

```
$json['pobject'][] = array('pname'=>'Superman', 'pid'=>4);
```

Then, you can overwrite old text file with:

```
file_put_contents( 'obdatabase.json', json_encode( $json ) );
```

#### Edit:

You have **already asked** for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397257/how-to-add-and-delete-data-to-a-json-file-from-a-php-file). The correct way to act on Stack Overflow is:

- If you don't understand the answer(s) or the answer(s) doesn't match your question, continue discussion in the precedent question;
- If the question is closed, mark an answer as right and **then** ask for new question.

This out of respect for users that dedicate their time to find a solution and out of respect for future visitors that can easy understand if a question has a valid answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you get gthe json from the file then parse it to php json_encode()

Comment: Thx but could you include some code. I can't find a satisfied answer online. Thanks.

Comment: sure, modifying the answer

Comment: great :) give me a left with the vote cuz someone flagged me down while i am just trying to help. I didnt notice that you are using json and that dude just didnt even take 2 seconds and pam voted me down

Comment: what if I want to delete an object which has a unique ID for my example? say, I want to delete the object which has id(pid in my example)== 3

Comment: Delete entire { "pname":"Justinbieber" , "pid":"3" }  given the pid==3